# Неочевидное поведение итераторов

Tags: c#, .net

В одной книге встретил вот такое высказывание:

> Итераторы всех коллекций .NET Framework являются изменяемыми
>   структурами. Это, с одной стороны, избавляет от дополнительного
>   выделения памяти в управ- ляемой куче при проходе по коллекции, а с
>   другой стороны, может привести к не- ожиданному результату. Попробуйте
>   предугадать поведение следующего кода (листинг 4.8), а потом запустите
>   его, чтобы проверить свою догадку. Листинг 4.8. Неочевидное поведение
>   итераторов

```
var x = new {Items = new List<int> {1, 2, 3}.GetEnumerator()};
while (x.Items.MoveNext())
{
Console.WriteLine(x.Items);
}
```

Цикл действительно становится бесконечным. Однако, почему?

Есть ли еще какие-нибудь не очевидные вещи в итераторах?

Comment: Это не неочевидная вещь в итераторах, это неочевидная вещь в мутабельных структурах.

Comment: Вот вам ещё статья по теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/

Answer (score 2):

`x.Items` это публичное поле объекта, при этом оно является структурой, а при обращении к таким полям создаётся временная переменная. То есть на самом деле этот код выглядит приблизительно так (сам код синтаксически не верен):

```
var x = new { Items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.GetEnumerator() };
while (var tmp = x.Items, tmp.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Items);
}
```

То есть при каждой итерации `while` создаётся копия значения `x.Items`, которая и изменяется методом `MoveNext()`, но вот само `x.Items` остаётся прежним.

Вообще эти проблемы хорошо описаны в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124404/).